# View with table view only works with default View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need a settings screen in my app which I intend to create with a simple static table view. Unfortunately I ran into an issue. When I assign a custom view controller to the view in my storyboard the views table goes black during runtime.

[image: faulty static table example]

This is despite the view controller not changing the default behaviour. I only override one method at this point, to put the Settings string in the title.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class SettingsViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func loadView() {
        self.title = "Settings"
    }

}
```

When I remove the custom view controller the table appears normally.
[image: correct table]

I segue into the view using the following code.

```
guard let vc = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "settingsViewController") as? UITableViewController else { // or SettingsViewcontroller for the first version
                print("Could not instantiate view controller with identifier of type SettingsViewController")
                return
            }            
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated:true)
```

What could cause this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call `super.loadView()`, You are overriding the `UITableViewController's loadView()` and not calling the super class method, Due to that you are getting black screen.

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

    class SettingsViewController: UITableViewController {

        override func loadView() {
            self.title = "Settings"
            super.loadView()
        }

    }
```